# Error on vagrant up for laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

Hi there I have encountered below error after running vagrant up:

```
    $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "83b1dbca-4d9f-4828-a544-d8a88124eafe", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'homestead-7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

The vagrant used to work just fine and this error happens right after Windows 10 update. 
I have tried below commands non resolve the issue:

```
vagrant reloead
vagrant reload --provision
```

vagrant and homestead version:

```
$ vagrant -v 
Vagrant 1.9.1 
$ homestead -v Laravel 
Homestead version 3.1.0
```

I couldn't run virtual box application even through run as administrator option (no error/warning). I check the version through cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage 
--version 5.1.8r111374
```

Event Viewer error upon virtual box run:

```
Faulting application name: VirtualBox.exe, version: 5.1.8.11374, time stamp: 0x58062715
Faulting module name: VirtualBox.exe, version: 5.1.8.11374, time stamp: 0x58062715
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000139bd
Faulting process id: 0x15fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2df9836f7498f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
Report Id: e94ebe5e-a1f3-4157-92a5-3452486712ef
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: vagrant and homestead version:
`$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.9.1
$ homestead -v
Laravel Homestead version 3.1.0`

Comment: I can't update vagrant:
`$ vagrant box update
==> homestead-7: Box 'laravel/homestead' not installed, can't check for updates.`

Comment: what is virtualbox version?

Comment: i couldn't run virtual box application even through run as administrator option (no error/warning). I check the version through cmd: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage --version
5.1.8r111374`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue today after the latest Windows update. Installing the latest version of Virtual Box (5.1.22) solved this for me. I was at 5.1.6.

You may need to also update the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Comment: I download and install the [virtual box latest version](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) the issue resolved

Comment: Same issue, same solution and same result, but I had to uninstall McAfee on top of above actions.